# MVC2 - Exclude date and time column from Update method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, edit, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

I am tring update a record and want to exclude one column from the update, i have this field that is populated with GetDate() as a default value in sql, so when the update takes place i want this field to be left as it is,

```
 [ScaffoldColumn(false)]

    [Column] public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }
```

Ive tried using both ScaffoldColumnFalse from dataannotaions and HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false) but when i try to save the changes an error is thrown

```
 sqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

From what i understand this is thrown due to a null value being passed to the RegisterdDate field,

Ive also tried using bind Exclude in the ActionResult stub to no avail

```
 public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "RegisteredDate")] Customer customer)
```

Anyone any ideas on where I am going wrong here?

Kind Regards

Liam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Steve Sandersons blog, [Partial Validation in ASP.NET MVC 2](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/02/19/partial-validation-in-aspnet-mvc-2/). His approach is to validate only incoming values from the view. This may work in your case.

Comment: Tried this to no avail, when debugging i can see that when customersTable.Context.SubmitChanges runs null values are being passed for all the fields from the customer object so i think this might explain why the error is occuring, this is being passed for the date field {01/01/0001 00:00:00

Comment: Fixed my update method, but this error is still occuring, i have used steve sandersons ValidateOnlyIncomingAttributes but this value {01/01/0001 00:00:00 } is still being passed to registered date???

Comment: Can you post an example (edit your post) of the controller action?